# Check Prime Extension

Tags: c#, primes

This method should check a number to be a prime

```
public static bool IsPrime(this long value)
{
    if (value < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        int boundary = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(value));
        return Enumerable.Range(2, boundary-1).AsParallel().Any(x => value % x != 0);
    }
}
```

but doesn't work in every case. E.g. `9` is a prime number according to this method but `3x3=9` so it's wrong. I don't see the mistake in the method.

Comment: Not a good candidate for `AsParallel` because the operation `value % x != 0` is not time consuming.

Comment: efficiency: the value doesn't need to be checked against other even numbers than `2`. So you can ignore a check against `4,6,8,10,...`

Comment: So, what's the reason for a bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that this is not something to use with AsParallel(), your problem is that

```
return Enumerable.Range(2, boundary - 1).AsParallel().Any(x => value % x != 0);
```

should be

```
return Enumerable.Range(2, boundary - 1).AsParallel().All(x => value % x != 0);
```

You should have been using `.All()`, not `.Any()`.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the condition:

```
return !Enumerable.Range(2, boundary - 1).AsParallel().Any(x => value % x == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code which is more efficient:

```
  var primes = Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
    .Where(i => i != 1 && !Enumerable.Range(2, i - 2).Any(j => i % j == 0));
```